# Timepicker in flutter OK button navigation

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a timepicker in our flutter application that we want to send the user to a different screen upon clicking "OK". I am not seeing an "onconfirm" option for the timepicker. How is the achieved?

Heres the code:

```
 Future<TimeOfDay> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    initialTime: _time,
);
if (picked != null && picked != _time) {
    setState(() {
    _time = picked;
    _clicked = true;
  });
}
return picked;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you check the condition whether `picked` is `!null` and `setState()` time, inside your `if` code you can directly navigate to other screen. Sample working code below:

```
Future _showTimePicker(BuildContext context) async {
    TimeOfDay timeOfDay =
        await showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: TimeOfDay.now());

     if (timeOfDay != null) {
       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextScreen()));
     }
    }
```

You may just need to modify it per your current code, but it should be after you set state. Then once you tap `OK`, you will be navigated to other screen.

Hope it helps.